# Angular Material Select component not showing the dropdown when clicked

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular14

I have an Angular 14 app with a form with a mat-select field that doesn't show the dropdown with the options when clicked on the field. There are no errors in the console. And I have imported MatInputModule, MatSelectModule among others.

This is the html file:-

```
<form
class="form-container"
[formGroup]="sampleForm"
novalidate
(submit)="submitForm(sampleForm, formDirective)"
#formDirective="ngForm">
<mat-expansion-panel expanded>
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-title
      ><b>About you</b></mat-panel-title
    >
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12">
    <mat-label
      ><b>Gender</b></mat-label
    >
    <mat-select formControlName="gender">
      <mat-option
        *ngFor="let gender of genderOptions"
        [value]="gender.value"
      >
        {{ gender.label }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select> </mat-form-field
  >
</mat-expansion-panel>
</form>
```

And this is in the ts file:-

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  FormGroupDirective,
} from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-sample-component',
  templateUrl: './sample.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sample.component.scss'],
})
export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {
  genderOptions: any[] = [
    { label: 'Male', value: 'MALE' },
    { label: 'Female', value: 'FEMALE' },
    { label: 'Other', value: 'OTHER' },
    { label: 'Prefer not to say', value: 'NOSAY' },
  ];
  sampleForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    gender: []
  })
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
  ngOnInit() {}

  submitForm(form: FormGroup, formDirective: FormGroupDirective) {
    console.log('form => ', form);
  }
}
```

And I'm importing these modules into the app.module.ts file:-

```
  MatButtonModule,
  MatCheckboxModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatProgressSpinnerModule,
  MatSidenavModule,
  MatDialogModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatTooltipModule,
  CdkAccordionModule,
  MatExpansionModule,
  BrowserModule,
  AppRoutingModule,
  BrowserAnimationsModule,
```

And this is a section of the imports from my package.json file to show the version number:-

```
"@angular/animations": "^14.0.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^14.0.0",
"@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^14.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^14.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^14.0.0",
"@angular/material": "^14.0.0",
```

I feel like I've taken care of everything. I have even tried to remove the expansion panel to see if that solves the issue and it's the same thing. Also , I tried to have options listed manually instead of the ngFor and it is still the same.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Your code looks ok https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v14-playground-u1mskn?file=src/main.ts

Comment: Thanks for taking the effort to put it on stackblitz. I'm honestly dumbstuck because I'm able to use the select dropdowns properly on other areas of my app, but only in this component it is not working out. It's so bizarre.